# py2neo: neo4j.CypherQuery() fails in multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, neo4j, multiprocessing, py2neo

I try to do a few CypherQuery() in parallel using multiprocessing.Pool.

When I run the neo4j.CypherQuery() non-parallel, it works fine. When I run only 1 neo4j.CypherQuery() on multiprocessing.Pool, it works fine. As soon as I start 2 or more neo4j.CypherQuery() processes, it fails with the error message below.

```
from mulitprocessing import Pool
from py2neo import neo4j

pool = Pool(processes=4)

db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")

def cypher_query(db):
    try:
        # very simple cypher query
        query_string = "MATCH (n:Label) RETURN n.name, n"
        query = neo4j.CypherQuery(db, query_string)
        result = query.execute()
        return_dict = {}

        for r in result:
            return_dict[r[0]] = r[1]
        return return_dict

    except:
        # print stack trace
        print('%s' % (traceback.format_exc()))

result1 = pool.apply_async(cypher_query, [db])
result2 = pool.apply_async(cypher_query, [db])

# close pool and wait for all processes to finish
pool.close()
pool.join()   

# here I would collect results, something fails before
result1.get()
result2.get()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my/script.py", line 237, in my_function
    query = neo4j.CypherQuery(db, query_string)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 976, in __init__
    self._cypher = Resource(graph_db.__metadata__["cypher"])
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 320, in __metadata__
    self.refresh()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 342, in refresh
    self._metadata = ResourceMetadata(self._get().content)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py", line 532, in content
    elif self.is_text:
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py", line 513, in is_text
    return self.content_type.partition("/")[0] == "text"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'partition'
```

I don't quite get the Error message. I tried it with different Cypher queries and both execute() and stream() but it allways fails. All queries run fine non-parallel. Obviously, I am missing something that breaks parallelization of my function, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: It looks like on the second call the http content-type header is lost, but I have no idea why.

Comment: I had a look at httpstream to figure out what's going on, but I still don't get it ;) I guess it can't be multiprocessing in general, because it works when I spawn a single process with CypherQuery().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am aware that py2neo/httpstream do not work with multiprocessing and there is an issue in GitHub representing this:

https://github.com/nigelsmall/httpstream/issues/3

However, as I do not have any need for multiprocessing myself and know very little about this module, no progress has been made in resolving this issue. I would be happy for a contributor to look into this and provide a patch but so far no-one has volunteered to do so.

Comment: OK. I can try to look into py2neo and multiprocessing. I've used queues (celery, python-rq) which also depend on Pickle and it works. Serialization was my first idea. Let's see if I find the time and Python mojo to figure this out ... if so I'll post something on GitHub.

Comment: FWIW a patch would almost certainly only be required for the httpstream project, not for py2neo itself.

Comment: Add the end of this article, there is a convenient workaround: http://www.tsartsaris.gr/how-to-speedup-the-creation-of-nodes-to-a-neo4j-database-with-py2neo-from-python

Answer (score 0):

This error is also seen when using http instead https in your database connection string in version 1.6.1